# Animate images from a image menu screen off screen when other image is pressed. css amd jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on trying to have a menu with images at 100% of the screen but only showing 25% of the image. When a image is clicked the other images transition off the screen to reveal the whole image below.

When I try to stick a transition on the screen it only does the transition on the image itself. I want it to affect the other images and move them off screen.

I've got jquery adding classes to the sibling images on click. The classes move the image off the screen and display the main image fine they just don't animate nicely. When I put a transition on it shows the image resizing rather then the other images moving.

jsfiddle of it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/539Y9/3/

jquery:

```
$(".imageMenuItem").click(
    function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(event.currentTarget).addClass('imageMenuItemOpen');    
      $(event.currentTarget).nextAll().addClass('imageMenuItemClosedRight');
      $(event.currentTarget).prevAll().addClass('imageMenuItemClosedLeft');
    }
  );
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imageMenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><img class='imageMenuImage' src="http://catvettucson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat-banner.jpg"></img></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><img class='imageMenuImage' src='http://i.imgur.com/rzMOLdj.jpg'></img></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><img class='imageMenuImage'  src="http://catvettucson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat-banner.jpg"></img></li>
    <li class="imageMenuItem"><img class='imageMenuImage' src='http://portfoliographicdesign.com/cats/images/cats_banner4.jpg'></img></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageMenu {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.imageMenu li {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1.0s ease;
}

.imageMenu li:first-child .imageMenuImage {
  left 0;
}

.imageMenu li:nth-child(2) .imageMenuImage {
  left: -25vw;
}

.imageMenu li:nth-child(3) .imageMenuImage {
  left: -50vw;
}

.imageMenu li:nth-child(4) .imageMenuImage {
  left: -75vw;
}

.imageMenuImage {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
}

.imageMenuItemOpen {
  width:100% !important;
}

.imageMenuItemOpen .imageMenuImage {
  width:100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.imageMenuItemClosedLeft .imageMenuImage {
  left: -100vw !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.imageMenuItemClosedRight .imageMenuImage {
  left: 100vw !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: avoid .imageMenu height property the image will show 100% height.

Comment: @Nith At the moment I want to clip the images. These aren't the images I'm going to use in the actual version and they're going to probably be clipped in that one. Unless there is some reason its messing with what I'm trying to do here I'll sort that out when I'm refining design